# Precise fit independent background in containers

Tags: html, css

I have a specific problem with my html & css.
I have a header with cover background and few boxes inside this header. I want to add hover effect with stylised part of header background image.
It is simple until I want get a precisely position of this hover on every RWD breakpoint (I think its impossible but I have to try although). The header background and boxes hover background are indepent of each other.

I have a simple markup & css. Do I have to use JS/jQuery to copy a header background properties to hovered box? I have no idea.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQBaA.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
}

.box:hover {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyLFe.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box3"></div>
    <div class="box box4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pls. see Full page to better understanding.
Any link/webage explaining this problem appreciated.

Comment: Can you add an example of what it should look like?

Comment: It's possible without any JS. Since you want this to be responsive, everything needs to be defined in %. You should define the position inside the wrapper and `background-position` for each box in %. That way the images are in sync. However you will probably have to make some tweaks depending on the viewport aspect ratio: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but I think that the effect, that you want, can be achieved with [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQBaA.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
}

.box:hover {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyLFe.jpg) no-repeat;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box3"></div>
    <div class="box box4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can divide the header image into separate boxes, i.e. box1 - box4.

I updated your code, see if this is the result that you want. Note that i changed the hovered image to grayscale for faster work, you can easily change it to background image to each of the elements.

[See here for the result](https://jsfiddle.net/kb342wdz/).

### CSS

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/K0a4IMX.jpg);
}

.box2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/nJ959iP.jpg);
}

.box3 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/96SG6Zx.jpg);
}

.box4 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/ulhn4Db.jpg);
}

.box:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100);
}
```

[See here for the result](https://jsfiddle.net/kb342wdz/).